# Git branching: There and Back Again

Tags: git, github, git-branch

When I work on a feature, quite often I stumble upon certain parts in codebase that can be improved. I want to have those parts fixed, but I don't want to have them fixed in current feature branch, since they are merely related, if at all.

Therefore I do the following:

1. `git add -A`
2. `git commit -m "WIP. Be back soon..."`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git pull origin master`
5. `git checkout -b quickfix-something`
6. ...make improvement in the code...
7. `git commit -m "Fix this and that"`
8. `git push my_origin quickfix-something`
9. `hub pull-request -b origin:master -h my_origin:quickfix-something` (this is just GitHub specific PR opening)
10. `git checkout my_feature_branch`
11. `git reset --soft HEAD~1`
12. ...continue working on my feature branch...

**But this takes so long!**

Instead I want to do something like this:

1. `git back-and-forth --start "my_new_branch"`
2. ...make improvement in the code...
3. `git back-and-forth --finish -m "Fix this and that"`
4. ...continue working on my feature branch...

I know git-flow does something like that, but I don't want to take all it's burden with me, unless there's away to minimally set it up the way I want. Also, if I'm not mistaken, it doesn't support automatically opening the PRs on GitHub.

Before I write my own script to do the same, here are my questions:

1. **is there any existing git tool that does what I want?**
2. **unless 1, is there any other approach to do what I want, only with fewer steps?**

Comment: You can create an alias; it's possible to define shell functions as aliases which execute multiple commands like that `my_alias = "f() { # Do stuff }; f"`.

Comment: Or alternativly just a usual shell function.

Comment: Did you miss a command?  I don't think `git add` accepts the `-m` flag.

Comment: Thanks, @onionjake, you're right. Just fixed it (it should be two commands instead of 1).

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own script seems like your best bet for #1.  You might be able to combine groups of commands as simple aliases to avoid writing a full blown script.

As far as #2, you can eliminate some steps by using `git stash` and not checking out master.

1. `git stash`
2. `git fetch`
3. `git checkout -b quickfix-something origin/master`
4. ...make improvement in the code...
5. `git commit -am "Fix some stuff"`
6. `git push my_origin quickfix-something`
7. `hub pull-request ...`
8. `git checkout my_feature_branch`
9. `git stash pop`
10. ...continue working on my feature branch...

Your original question has 10 commands. This shortens it by 2 commands to 8.

---

*Below is another option that I thought up while trying to eliminate commands. It doesn't save any typing and sure makes life a whole lot more complicated compared to the above solution.  Please don't use it.*

**Alternate insanity:** The rebase method.  ***Don't use this for reals, unless you like mixing LSD and chainsaws.***   This might run into conflicts on the rebase depending on the upstream changes relative to your 'improvements'.

1. `git stash`
2. ...make improvement in the code... yes, do it on your feature branch
3. `git commit -am "Fix some stuff i need elsewhere"`
4. `git fetch`
5. `git rebase HEAD^ --onto origin/master`
6. `git push my_origin my_feature_branch:quickfix-something`
7. `hub pull-request ...`
8. `git reset --hard  ORIG_HEAD^`
9. `git stash pop`
10. ...continue working on feature branch ...